# How can I use adjustbox in \sectionmark?

Tags: macros, header-footer, fancyhdr, adjustbox

I want to use adjustbox in \sectionmark but it doesn't work. Is there a work-around for this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1 \adjustbox{valign=t}{\rule{1.5pt}{\baselineskip}} \thesection}}

\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{}


\begin{document}

\chapter{An example chapter}

\section{An example section}

\blindtext[25]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Oh dear, shame on me. But the problem still exists together with the \sectionmark command. I have changed the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both `\rule` and `\adjustbox` are fragile commands, so you should use `\protect` in front of them when in moving arguments (which the argument of `\sectionmark` is).

However, there's a better way to obtain your wish:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{%
  \markright{#1 \strut\vrule width 1.5pt\relax\ \thesection}}

\fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{}


\begin{document}

\chapter{An example chapter}

\section{An example section}

\blindtext[25]

\end{document}
```

[image]